# How can I rewrite links with JavaScript or jQuery and a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey

Looking to modify Yahoo Answers links to remove some parts, saving just the `qid` and replacing `index` with `answer`.

So this:

```
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AhT5ZZwbMiGWdQZDSxD1ML305nNG;_ylv=3?qid=20121004094847AAjekoj
```

becomes this:

```
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/answer?qid=20121004094847AAjekoj
```

I know there are ways to rewrite links with `.htaccess` but in this case, it would need to be a Greasemonkey script since the task would be done on sites I visit, and not my websites.

Comment: Is it always going to be one level of subdirectories, or might there be more? Is it always going to be the same domain name, but are there more than one? Are there any links that you do not want messed with?

Comment: It will all be the same directory. I don't mind adding that its for Yahoo Answers - when you see a list of questions I'd want to just click it and have it take me right to the answer box. So, http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AhT5ZZwbMiGWdQZDSxD1ML305nNG;_ylv=3?qid=20121004094847AAjekoj would become http://answers.yahoo.com/question/answer?qid=20121004094847AAjekoj and so on.

Comment: So there is a subdirectory (`question`). That means Andrew Kozak's answer will not work. In the future, give as much information as possible: giving the exact URL type in question lets us tailor it to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General, this should do it (**Complete GM script**):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Replace yahoo-answers links
// @include  http://answers.yahoo.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change introduced
    in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var targLinks   = $("a[href*='question/index']");
targLinks.each ( function () {
    if (/\bqid=\w+/i.test (this.href) ) {
        var newHref = this.href

        var newPath = this.pathname.replace (/\/question\/index.+$/, "/question/answer");
        var newURL  = this.protocol + "//"
                    + this.host
                    + newPath
                    + this.search
                    + this.hash
                    ;
        this.href   = newURL;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Won't the `index.+$` include the `qid` that Daniel wants to keep?

Comment: No, because it's operating on the `pathname`.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, that would do it. +1'd

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you need here would be this:

```
/(http:\/\/answers.yahoo.com\/questions\/)index.*(?qid=.*)$/i
```

And you'd replace it with this:

```
/$1answer$2/
```

I don't really know a lot about Greasemonkey, though, so I can't give you more than this. Hopefully someone with more knowledge of Greasemonkey comes along and provides a better answer.

Comment: @DanielDoes: it's possible that Greasemonkey uses `\1` and `\2` instead of `$1` and `$2`, just for another thing to try if this doesn't work.

Comment: No Greasemonkey is just JS with a couple privileges turned back on.  The regex is the same (`$1`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, it works good. I made sure to blog about this and of course I credited it back to this page.

Comment: @DanielDoes: Personally I suspect BrockAdams's answer will help you more, but in any event, you should check the answer that helped you most for future users, so anyone with the same question can easily find the best answer. Upvoting any helpful or useful answers is also encouraged.

Comment: interesting, you need some reputation to upvote first. oh well, makes sense I guess. wouldn't want dopey users to have much influence.

Comment: @DanielDoes: You can always accept an answer. You actually get a bit of reputation for doing so (though you're right, I forgot you need 15 rep to upvote; if you accept an answer, you'll still be 7 short).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
/(http:\/\/answers\.yahoo\.com\/question)\/index.+[?&]qid=([^&#]+)/g
```

with

```
"$1/answer?quid=$2"
```

Comment: The `[?&]` is a nice touch, but heh, it's `qid` not `quid`.